# Why does the less than equal to symbol not appear as intended in the following code?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, mathjax

When I use the following code on stats.stackexchange.com (which is powered by MathJax) the `\le` does not render properly. Is this a bug in MathJax or am I not using the `\le` symbol properly?

```
$X_3 = 
\begin{cases} 
  X_{31} & \mbox{if }Y_1 Y_2 \mbox{ >  0} \\\
  X_{32} & \mbox{if }Y_1 Y_2 \mbox{ \le 0} 
\end{cases}$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- use `\le` in math mode, e.g. `\mbox{if $Y_1 Y_2 \le 0$}`
  (yes, that's math mode inside text)
- use T1 font encoding to get the > symbol correctly typeset in text mode:
  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` Otherwise, with standard OT1 encoding, the output
  wouldn't be > except you use math mode as well: `$>$`
- On standard LaTeX you should also use `\text{...}` rather than `\mbox{...}`.

Comment: Beat me to it!  As the question is about MathJaX, the first of these seems the most likely - though I would recommend that the second and fourth `\mbox`s not be `\mbox`s at all but simply `Y_1 Y_1 \le 0`.

Comment: Btw. in normal LaTeX I would use `\text` instead of `\mbox` with amsmath.

Comment: I would actually typeset this as follows:

$X_3 = \begin{cases}
    X_{31} & \text{if $Y_1 Y_2 > 0$} \    X_{32} & \text{if $Y_1 Y_2 \le 0$}
\end{cases}$

(Yes, the \text contains math.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the math mode for math symbols; remove extra `mbox` commands: `$ X_3 = \begin{cases} X_{31} & \mbox{if }Y_1 Y_2 > 0 \\ X_{32} & \mbox{if }Y_1 Y_2 \le 0 \end{cases}$`